# What the meaning of "bottom" referred to a time period

Tags: meaning

In the sentence

> A lasted till the bottom of B

where B is an event which, in its turn, lasted some years, "bottom" is the beginning of B or the end of B?

I found it in an economic article, the actual sentence is

> the regulatory wave lasted till the bottom of the world 2007-2009
>   crisis

(Henry Penikas, "History of Banking Regulation as Developed by the Basel Committee on Banking Supervision in 1974-2014 (Brief Overview)", 2015).

Comment: It's a new one on me.

Comment: Bottom is used to indicate the “lowest” part of something. What “events” do A and B refer to?  For instance: “at the bottom of sth” *The time to buy is at the bottom of a recession.*

Comment: The only time I have heard this type of phrase is in relation to a [baseball inning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inning) and it refers to the second part of the inning, so my gut tells me its the end. but yeah, it depends on what A and B are

Comment: @user240918 I found it in an economic article "the regulatory wave lasted till the bottom of the world 2007-2009 crisis"

Comment: @CarLaTeX that clearly refers to the “worst” phase of the crisis, which may have taken place anytime during the the period 2007-2009.

Comment: @user240918 Thank you, I'll add the citation in my question, if you'll post an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @user240918 - The bottom was in March of ‘09.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Investopedia](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/b/bottom.asp)

> A bottom is the lowest price reached by a financial security, commodity, index or economic cycle. *Often, a specific time span is used to determine a bottom, and that timeframe can be a year, month or even intraday.*

In your case “bottom” refers to the worst phase of the 2007-2009 economic/financial crisis